# New to linux: C++ opening and closing usb port issues

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port, usb, usbserial

New developer, Linux, C++, USB - Serial Adapter.

I've completed a program where I am able to write to the USB port. However, if I change my code, make, log back in as root, and try to write to the port again, it doesn't go through. It'll only work if I remove the USB cable from the computer and reseat it before attempting sending data again. If you need more info let me know.

I'm on two different computers and have no way of copying and pasting but here is the gist of what I'm doing.

```
int fd = 0;
int iOut = 0;
char *ComPort = "/dev/ttyUSB0";

fd=open(ComPort, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

if(fd == -1)
  cout << "unable to open" << endl;

// blah blah getting data ready to be sent
// create a block of 50 hex characters to be sent : DB

iOut = write(fd, $DB, sizeof(DB));

// blah blah error checking

close(fd);
return(0);
```

Comment: `it doesn't go through` - please explain, what error exactly you have. Also, what happens if you run your program twice without changing it?

Comment: '0_CREAT' is that 'O_CREAT'? 0(zero)-O(capital o)

Comment: @AlexFarber I'm not receiving an error per say. What I'm working on has a display that I want to show a particular number on. So if I start fresh and have it display 1, it'll work. Then if I change my src code to have it display 2, it'll stay at 1. If I unplug the USB from the computer and reseat it and send my data again, it'll display 2. If I don't change the code and resend the same data, it stays at 1.

Comment: @Surt I fixed it in the above code. Thank you.

Comment: What is `DB` and what is `$DB` ?

Comment: To check whether this is program or hardware problem: make two executables, one that displays 1, another that displays 2. Run one after another - what result do you have? What happens, if you display 1, sleep, then display 2 in the same program?

Comment: DB is an array of 50 hex characters @PaulR which end up being the data I send via the USB to Serial Adapter to my display.

Comment: Can you show the declaration for `DB` and can you explain what `$DB` is (in the call to `write`) ?

Comment: Where does you cout go? if you can see it on a monitor somewhere you can add some more to see where the problem is if you don't have a debugger. My guess from previous experience would be access rights, file still open, and missing send signal from serial.

Comment: @AlexFarber I created the second executable and sent both back to back. My first ./executable ran perfectly and my number changed to 2. When I ran ./executable2 it didn't display a 1. I'm getting a reading on my USB adapter (of Red LED's which don't light up on the first time I send data).

Comment: cout is displayed on my actual Linux box. The device I'm writing to has it's own display that reads the bytes of &DB and displays the number I want on it's display. @Surt This is where my Linux / c++ knowledge fades. I am logged in as root though. I'm not sure how to check the rest of that.

Answer (score 2):

@Surt @alexfarber I had a talk with a coworker on this and we concluded that this is most likely a hardware issue with my display or usb to serial adapter. I believe the only way this can work with this particular adapter is by turning off the power to it and turning it back on in order to reflect what it would see when being removed and reseated manually. I dont believe this is possible but I'll start another thread with anything I may run into. I appreciate you all taking the time to help with this, I did learn a number of other things I didn't know before hand so this was still very helpful. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Take at look at chapter 3.2 here http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/x115.html
add some of the error checking first so you can see where if fails. The perror line will help there.

```
if (fd <0) {perror(ComPort ); exit(-1); } // note the exit which your code doesn't have.
```

This should now tell you some more info and add

```
if (errno) {perror(ComPort ); exit(-1); }
```

after all operations, read, write and set things on the fd.

now add the newtio part of 3.2 to your program in case some handshake failed. You must change it so it conforms with the display.

The final version of your program might be more like 3.3.

Comment: where did you get errno? @Surt

Comment: all file operations sets it, its a thread local global variable, see http://linux.die.net/man/3/open

Comment: also I added in if(fd<0){perror(ComPort);exit(-1); and no change in behavior when I started fresh (reseat USB) and without reseat. Still wrote first time and didn't fail after running a few times after that as well.

Comment: I added it right after declaring fd = open(ComPort ... );

Comment: and what about right after write? (and after close)

Comment: I placed it both before and after open() and write(). I am also printing cout << fd << "text of where it's located" << endl; before fd is declared, after it's declared, before write, after write, before close and after close... Before being declared it's 0, after open() it's 3, and remains 3 throughout the remaining code.

Comment: Use errno the other places, if errno is not zero there is an error.

Comment: I was missing #include <errno.h> I have been stopped right after fd = open () where errno == 0. however the response I receive is /dev/ttyUSB0: Success

Comment: '
    cout << "ComPort = " << ComPort << endl;

    fd = open (Comport, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

    if(errno == 0)
    {
    perror(ComPort);
    exit(-1);
    }

    cout << "fd = " << fd << endl;
`

I don't get fd = a number printed back

Comment: I posted it in multiple areas of my code checking for errno != 0 and I received no errors. More specifically, in the areas you had mentioned plus others.

Comment: Have you tried adding the handshaking from the example, if one of the two ends expect a specific handshake and the other doesn't it will fail too even though the program finishes, that is until the write buffer is full at your side.